# The function runtime is unable to start - Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management.ManagementClient'

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, spring-cloud-function

I deployed a new version of my Azure Functions based on Java. Now there is following error toast in the Azure portal under my Azure Function resource in a specific function:

```
Error: The function runtime is unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management.ManagementClient' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c'. Session Id: a9f3c42dbb524ceca2c5158df9460c97 Timestamp: 2019-12-02T18:21:46.680Z
```

It sounds for me a bit like that: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3363

The interesting thing is that I changed nothing except some minor Java code changes till the last deployment. Is the Function App Version automatically updated?

I also checked the logs via kudu and log stream (application logs).

logs:

```
2019-12-02T11:08:04.412 [Information] Starting JobHost 2019-12-02T11:08:04.415 [Information] Starting Host (HostId=functionapp-dtw-worker-dp-master, InstanceId=aaab65a2-acef-4e4c-a8be-c3a1b13a795c, Version=2.0.12888.0, ProcessId=6860, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=True, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=~2) 2019-12-02T11:08:04.467 [Information] Loading functions metadata 2019-12-02T11:08:04.495 [Information] 3 functions loaded 2019-12-02T11:08:04.812 [Information] Generating 3 job function(s) 2019-12-02T11:08:05.126 [Information] Found the following functions: Host.Functions.lastWillCronJobProcessor Host.Functions.serviceBusDeadLetterProcessor Host.Functions.serviceBusProcessor 2019-12-02T11:08:05.351 [Error] A host error has occurred during startup operation '7c3d76bc-730c-401a-86cb-27d04231d515'. System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management.ManagementClient' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c'. at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.Listeners.ServiceBusScaleMonitor..ctor(String functionId,EntityType entityType,String entityPath,String connectionString,Lazy1 receiver,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.Listeners.ServiceBusListener.<.ctor>b__18_0()
at System.Lazy1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode) at System.Lazy1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication,Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
at System.Lazy1.CreateValue() at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.Listeners.ServiceBusListener.GetMonitor() at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.HostListenerFactory.RegisterScaleMonitor(IListener listener,IScaleMonitorManager monitorManager) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\HostListenerFactory.cs : 107 at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.HostListenerFactory.CreateAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\HostListenerFactory.cs : 69 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.ListenerFactoryListener.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\ListenerFactoryListener.cs : 45 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.ShutdownListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\ShutdownListener.cs : 29 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\JobHost.cs : 101 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHost.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Host\ScriptHost.cs : 249 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at async Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebJobsScriptHostService.UnsynchronizedStartHostAsync(ScriptHostStartupOperation activeOperation,Int32 attemptCount,JobHostStartupMode startupMode) at C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\WebJobsScriptHostService.cs : 235
```

Log streaming:

Same logs as in the log file via kudu

Do you know why it stopped working? I have no plan to be honest. Did any configuration for the service bus trigger changes?

Check for a solution in the Azure portal
For issues in production, please check for a solution to common issues in the Azure portal before opening a bug. In the Azure portal, navigate to your function app => Platform features => Diagnose and solve problems and the relevant dashboards before opening your issue.

Investigative information
Please provide the following:

Timestamp: 2019-12-02T18:21:46.680Z
Function App version (1.0 or 2.0): 2.0.12888.0 (~2)
Function App name: functionapp-dtw-worker-dp-master
Application Setting:
FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME: java
Function name(s) (as appropriate): serviceBusProcessor
Session Id: a9f3c42dbb524ceca2c5158df9460c97
Region: West Europe
Related information
Provide any related information

Programming language used: Java with Spring Boot, Spring Cloud Functions
Links to source
Bindings used: ServiceBusTrigger, TimeTrigger

SUPPLEMENT: I updated the local dependencies like .NET Core Version to the newest v2.2.8 from here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

The update does not change the error message. I get the same error exception when I locally start the function with the maven plugin "azure-functions-maven-plugin" version 1.3.4, as you can see below:

```
[12/2/2019 10:44:26 PM] Starting JobHost [12/2/2019 10:44:26 PM] Starting Host (HostId=n900b368-1683948780, InstanceId=889e113f-9129-4a24-8fbf-9b560addd68e, Version=2.0.12888.0, ProcessId=2368, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=False, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=(null)) [12/2/2019 10:44:26 PM] Loading functions metadata [12/2/2019 10:44:26 PM] 3 functions loaded [12/2/2019 10:44:26 PM] Generating 3 job function(s) [12/2/2019 10:44:26 PM] Found the following functions: [12/2/2019 10:44:26 PM] Host.Functions.lastWillCronJobProcessor [12/2/2019 10:44:26 PM] Host.Functions.serviceBusDeadLetterProcessor [12/2/2019 10:44:26 PM] Host.Functions.serviceBusProcessor [12/2/2019 10:44:26 PM] [12/2/2019 10:44:26 PM] A host error has occurred during startup operation '03187631-f70a-45f5-9c3e-008568c4c6a4'. [12/2/2019 10:44:26 PM] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management.ManagementClient' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=3.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c'. [12/2/2019 10:44:26 PM] Stopping JobHost
```

GitHub Issue Report: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5317

Do you have any suggestion to solve that problems?

Comment: Try to downgrade version of `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` from 3.0.2 to 2.7.6 to see whether this error can be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your hints and tips! I solved it via deleting the faulty bin directory. For more details, see: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5317

Excerpt from the solution from: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5317

I have set the Application Settings "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE" to 1 and therefore I deployed a new version without bin directory and now it is working again. Thank you really much.

Detailed procedure for Azure Functions (Windows, Code, Java):

1. mvn clean install or mvn clean package
2. delete bin directory from /target/azure_function//
3. mvn azure-functions:deploy

PS: I am using maven plugin for Azure Functions.

pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.4</version>
<plugin>
```

Comment: SUPPLEMENT: The same steps (delete bin directory) are also necessary when you want to run the Azure Function locally.

Hopefully this strange bug with the creation of a faulty bin directory will be fixed in a near future release! I think the behavior is triggered by the maven plugin with the azure functions core tools.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the deployment somehow removes the installed extensions. I just had the same error with a TS function after deployment from VSCode. As a workaround I started the creation of a new function in the same function app using the same template as I used for the other functions in the app (e. g. Azure Service Bus Topic trigger). In my case this triggered a new installation of the required extensions and the error was gone.